# How to use ChangeNotifier with a abstract class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, overriding, abstract-class

In my dart application, I wanted to use ChangeNotifier for my authentication class.

I have an abstract class and another class implements the methods.

```
abstract class AuthBase {
  Future<void> signIn(String email, String password);
  Future<void> signUp(String email);
  Future<void> signOut();
}

class Auth with ChangeNotifier implements AuthBase {
...
}
```

As you can see ChangeNotifier is not used with the base class.

What I would like to do is use ChangeNotifier with the abstract class. But not sure how to override the methods in Auth class;

```
@override
  void addListener(listener) {
    // TODO: implement addListener
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement hasListeners
  bool get hasListeners => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  void notifyListeners() {
    // TODO: implement notifyListeners
  }

  @override
  void removeListener(listener) {
    // TODO: implement removeListener
  }
```

Can someone provide some help with this?

Comment: If you use `class Auth extends AuthBase` instead of `... implements ...`, then you wouldn't need to re-implement the `ChangeNotifier` interface in `Auth`.

Comment: Hi Janaka! How did you solve this? My problem is that with Provider you have to instantiate de AuthBase in MultiProvider() or something like that but as it's abstract you can't instantiate it, did you discovered some way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: @Juli15, it was taking too long to figure out, so I didn't implement a solution.

Comment: Refer to this link this might help you to solve the problem,
https://medium.com/flutter-nyc/introducing-property-change-notifier-10e6d27080a3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provider documentation has an example for that case: https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider#can-i-consume-an-interface-and-provide-an-implementation

```
abstract class ProviderInterface with ChangeNotifier {
  ...
}

class ProviderImplementation with ChangeNotifier implements ProviderInterface {
  ...
}

class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  build(context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<ProviderInterface>(context);
    return ...
  }
}

ChangeNotifierProvider<ProviderInterface>(
  create: (_) => ProviderImplementation(),
  child: Foo(),
),
```